# How to add tuples y values if x values are the same?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

```
start = [(1,2),(3,4),(1,3),(3,5)]
```

How can I add the tuples y values if the x values are the same efficiently (I am working with 700,000 tuples)?

```
end = [(1,5),(3,9)]
```

What I am trying:

I am trying to convert my list of tuples to a list of individual dictionaries. However, this doesn't look to be the most efficient method to me.

However then I can't figure out how to convert my list of tuples to a list of individual dictionaries.

I tried dict(start) and this:

```
a = []
for lv in length_view:
    a.append(dict(lv))
```

How else do I go about this?

And then I was going to try to use:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for some_dictionary in some_list:
    c.update(some_dictionary)

[{key: value} for key, value in c.items()]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method I can think of, using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is -

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(int)
>>> for a, b in start:
...     dic[a] += b
...
>>> list(dic.items())
[(1, 5), (3, 9)]
```

If you are using Python 2.x , you do not need the `list(..)` around `dic.items()` , as `.items()` returns a list in python 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Use `defaultdict` function  from collections module.

```
from collections import defaultdict
start = [(1,2),(3,4),(1,3),(3,5)]
d = defaultdict(list)
for x,y in start:
    d[x].append(y)

print [(i,sum(j)) for i,j in d.items()]
```

Comment: Why use a list as the defaultdict container when you end up summing the values anyway?

Comment: poke, later that i realized.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to create a dictionary with unique keys and relevant list of values then loop over its items and calculate the `sum` for values :

```
>>> start = [(1,2),(3,4),(1,3),(3,5)]
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in start:
...   d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
... 

>>> [(i,sum(j)) for i,j in d.items()]
[(1, 5), (3, 9)]
```

Or as a more efficient way use `collections.defaultdict` :

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for i,j in start:
...     d[i]+=j
... 
>>> d.items()
[(1, 5), (3, 9)]
```